# I'm trying to create a calculator with GUI.how can i update label when i press a button

Tags: python, calculator

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

input_1 =[]


def num_0():
    input_1.append(0)
    label.configure(text="test")
    return 0;

def num_1():
    input_1.append(1)
    label.configure(text="test")


root = Tk()
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.grid()

label = ttk.Label(frm, text="").grid(column=1, row=0)
ttk.Button(frm, text="1", command=num_1).grid(column=0, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

This is my code which is if there is some error, plz comment and

I'm trying to create a calculator with GUI. How can I update the label when I press a button.

but when I press that  button error pop up like this

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign label correctly:

```py
label = ttk.Label(frm, text="")
label.grid(column=1, row=0)
```

Comment: still, it,s did not work

Comment: Ok, maybe you need to provide the full error traceback.